# I want to get index in array which contains my value in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to get index in array which contains my value in C#.
For example, 
my array is:

```
byte[] primes = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13};
```

I will get index of value 11 for this example.  The array type is Byte.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use the [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx) method:

```
int[] array = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 };
int index = Array.IndexOf(array, 11); // returns 4
```

or with a byte array:

```
byte[] primes = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 };
int index = Array.IndexOf(array, (byte)11); // returns 4
```

Comment: Hi Darin, Why you add casting for byte value