# New Year Chaos HackerRank Practise Problem - C# solution optimization

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

```
static void minimumBribes(int[] q)
{
    Int32 TotalCount = 0;
    bool blnSuccess = true;
    Int32[] size = Ordering(q);
    for (int intI = 0; intI < q.Length; intI++)
    {
        Int32 Tempvariable = 0;
        Int32 TooChaotic = 0;
        Int32 index = Index(size,q[intI]);
        do
        {
            if (q[intI] != size[intI])
            {
                Tempvariable = size[index];
                size[index] = size[index - 1];
                size[index - 1] = Tempvariable;
                index = index - 1;
                TooChaotic = TooChaotic + 1;
                if (TooChaotic > 2)
                {
                    break;
                }
                TotalCount = TotalCount + 1;
            }
        } while (q[intI] != size[intI]);
        if (TooChaotic > 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too chaotic");
            blnSuccess = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (blnSuccess)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TotalCount);
    }
}

static int[] Ordering(int[] z)
{
    int[] r = new int[z.Length];
    r = z.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    return r;
}
static int Index(int[] z,int integer)
{
    for (int intI = 0; intI < z.Length; intI++)
    {
        if(z[intI]== integer)
        {
            return intI;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is working fine, but its runtime is too long.
I'm getting *"Terminated due to timeout"* in *HackerRank*. However, the solution is working fine on the local computer but it's taking more time.
Problem Link:https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem.

**Sample Input**

2 (the number of test cases)

5 (number of people in the queue)

2 1 5 3 4 (n space-separated integers describing the final state of the queue)

5 (number of people in the queue)

2 5 1 3 4 (*n* space-separated integers describing the final state of the queue).

It must print an integer representing the minimum number of bribes necessary, or Too chaotic if the line configuration is not possible.

**Output**
3

Too chaotic

**Question:**

How do I reduce its runtime? Presently, I am using an array.

Comment: My guess is that StackOverflow is not the correct platform for this kind of questions. Furthermore, there is no description of what this code does. I guess it would be better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Too many nested loops.. You can at least get rid off Index method and use a built in Array.IndexOf https://stackoverflow.com/a/6316165/10634638 https://stackoverflow.com/a/6316165/10634638

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem. this is the link of the problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've solved it a few weeks ago, this is my solution to the problem (100%)

```
static void minimumBribes(int[] q) {
    int bribe = 0;
    bool chaotic = false;
    int n = q.Length;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(q[i]-(i+1) > 2)
        {               
            chaotic = true;
            break;     
        }
        for (int j = Math.Max(0, q[i]-2); j < i; j++)
            if (q[j] > q[i]) 
                bribe++;
    }
    if(chaotic)
        Console.WriteLine("Too chaotic");
    else
        Console.WriteLine(bribe);
}
```

You don't need any other methods than the one provided by the challenge

Comment: What does `int j = Math.Max(0, q[i]-1-1);` mean? Why are you doing that?

Comment: @425nesp start with j at least 0. Avoid negative index

Comment: @425nesp because it's impossible for any number greater than q[i] reach position q[i] - 2 as only allow two bribes.

Comment: @Gianlucca Kindly provide the explanation of `int j = Math.Max(0, q[i]-1-1` What does this mean. I did you came up with this solution.?

Comment: the line int j = Math.max(0,q[i]-2) can be understand as follow : when we are ith index the number q[i] can give maximum 2 bribes hence it can move in left max 2 places hence q[i]-2 , but suppose we are at index 0 ,we can't move beyond that in left direction . Hence taking max of both values.

Comment: @425nesp Math.Max(0, q[i] - 2) is important for speed. This is so that you do not loop through the entire array. You only loop through where there can possibly be larger numbers without triggering "Too chaotic". eg nothing larger than 900 will get closer to the front than q[898], because then they would have to have bribed someone in front of them more than twice, so you have now looped through 898 less items in the array than you needed to